# No Ngmodule metadata found for 'Fm' in Angular 5 application

Tags: angular, angular5, cloud-foundry

There were few SO questions regarding this question, but none of those not worked for me, hence posting this question.
ng serve works fine but when I do "ng build --prod" and deploy the application to the cloud foundry this error showing.

I have already tried similar answers provided for this same question, but no luck

.angular-cli.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "skf-dashboard"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "keycloak.json",
        "favicon.ico",
        "Staticfile.txt"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
        "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
        "../node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/scss/mdb-free.scss",       
        "./styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
        "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
            "../src/assets/js/jquery.tempgauge.js",
        "../node_modules/keycloak-js/dist/keycloak.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "mindsphere": "environments/environment.mindsphere.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "skf-dashboard",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "PSL",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "prod": "ng build --prod",
    "oee-prod": "ng build --prod --base-href /oee/",
    "oee-mindsphere": "ng build --prod --environment=mindsphere",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-generic-table/column-settings": "^4.14.0",
    "@angular-generic-table/core": "^4.14.0",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.0",
    "@ngx-formly/bootstrap": "3.0.0",
    "@ngx-formly/core": "3.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.3.2",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.0.1",
    "angular-gridster2": "^5.3.1",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "keycloak-js": "^3.4.3",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.2.3",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-gauge": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.7.3",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.1.4",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "tether": "^1.4.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

index.html file

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>OEE Dashboard</title>
  <base href="/oee">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://static.eu1.mindsphere.io/osbar/v4/js/main.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="blue-grey lighten-5">
  <div id="_mdspcontent">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.ts file

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { KeycloakService } from './app/services/keycloak.service';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

configureAndRunApplication ();
function configureAndRunApplication () {
  let keycloakService : any = new KeycloakService;

  if (!environment.is_mindsphere) {
    console.log(keycloakService.keycloakStatus());
    KeycloakService.init().then( e => {
    if (keycloakService.hasRealmRole("oee_admin")){
      fetch('assets/config/config.json').then(resp => resp.json()).then(systemConfig => {
        window['system_config'] = systemConfig;
          platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
      });
    } else {
      keycloakService.logout();
    }
    }).catch(e => window.location.reload());
  } else {

    fetch('assets/config/config.json').then(resp => resp.json()).then(systemConfig => {
      window['system_config'] = systemConfig;

        platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
        console.log(keycloakService.keycloakStatus());
    });

  }
}
```

when I deployed and access the url It gives me "No Ngmodule metadata found for 'Fm'"
[image]

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem, the problem it seems regarding the compilation.
when I added optionally **--aot flag to false** in the build command, this error disappeared.

initially,`ng build --prod` (not worked for me)
then added the `ng build --aot=false --prod`